# Building & Running VLCLib Tutorial

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, vlc

https://wiki.videolan.org/LibVLC_Tutorial

Trying to get a running tutorial of the VLC libraries but getting the Exception in Visual Studios 2017:

"Exception thrown at 0x5A3EDF59(libvlc.dll) in Project1.exe: 0xC00000005: Access violation reading from location 0x0000000C."

Following the above tutorial.  All the code the same except for two places:

```
m = libvlc_media_new_path (inst, "C:\bb.mp4");
```

and calling Sleep instead of sleep() because of Windows environment.

I've copied the dlls from the VLC folder:  C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC into the same directory as my executable that is built.  Have also included the libraries and header files from:

C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\sdk\lib

C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\sdk\include

Not sure what else there is to do to get it to play the bb.mp4 on the root drive.

Comment: What is the value of `inst` (returned bu `libvlc_new`)? Also, make sure to double the _bkslash_ ( \ ) in strings: "_C:\\bb.mp4_".

Comment: I get 0x00000000 <NULL> for inst. That's all with the new path looking like C:\\bb.mp4

Comment: Yeah, that's _VStudio_ debugger's way of telling you that's an invalid value. For some reason `libvlc_new` failed. I suggest to do the `NULL` test on `inst` after `libvlc_new`, and if positive print `libvlc_errmsg()`.

Comment: "core libvlc error: No plugins found! Check your VLC installation."  Did some digging and saw a plugins folder in VLC.  There are about 20+ folders for plugins and they have a lot of dlls.  I'm guessing including those would help.  Not sure of any easy to do that besides copying lots of dlls into the executable directory.

Comment: I think they should be relative to the (_libvlc_) _.dll_, but I guess the _.exe_ folder will do.